# Django Haystack: error trying to build solr schema

Tags: django, search, solr, django-haystack

I'm getting the following error when attempting to run `./manage.py build_solr_schema`

```
NotImplementedError: Subclasses must provide a way to build their schema.
```

Here are what my two search indexes look like:

```
class BookSearchIndex (SearchIndex):
    text = CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    title = CharField(model_attr='title_web', boost=1.125)

    def index_queryset(self):
        return Book.objects.active().filter(publish_level='published')

site.register(Book, BookSearchIndex)


class AuthorSearchIndex (SearchIndex):
    text = CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    name = CharField(model_attr='name_display', boost=1.5)

    def index_queryset(self):
        return Author.objects.approved()

    def prepare(self, obj):
        data = super(AuthorSearchIndex, self).prepare(obj)
        data['boost'] = 1.5
        return data

site.register(Author, AuthorSearchIndex)
```

I'm running this locally and using the simple backend.  I was able to run `build_solr_schema` after creating the authors index.  But then when I setup the books index and tried to run it again I got the error mentioned.

Django 1.4.2,
Haystack 1.2.7

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm running this locally and using the **simple** backend.

you have to choose **solr** backend and configure haystack to use the **build_solr_schema** command.

```
HAYSTACK_SITECONF = 'search_sites'
HAYSTACK_SEARCH_ENGINE = 'solr'
HAYSTACK_SOLR_URL = '0.0.0.0:8983' #your solr server's address
```

see 
http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/v1.2.7/installing_search_engines.html#solr
for installing solr and
http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/v1.2.7/tutorial.html#modify-your-settings-py
for configuring haystack

Also, im assuming version 1.2.7 of haystack b/c in the 2.0.0 beta version of haystack I had trouble with **build_solr_schema** returning invalid schema.xml.

Comment: The HAYSTACK_SITECONF and other settings are no longer used as of django-haystack 2.0

Comment: My answer includes the versions of haystack it was meant for - I ignored v2 b/c it was beta-buggy at the time. Good to note though, v2.+ is where its at now, and a lot has changed.